# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapy-redis'

Tags: python, scrapy, distributed

I'm learning "distributed spider" recently and as you can see my screenshot or as below(Error)
[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnIUq.png)

```
2021-03-29 15:29:56 [twisted] CRITICAL:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1445, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = current_context.run(g.send, result)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 87, in crawl
    self.engine = self._create_engine()
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 101, in _create_engine
    return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 70, in __init__
    self.scraper = Scraper(crawler)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\scraper.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.itemproc = itemproc_cls.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python\lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 53, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python\lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 34, in from_settings
    mwcls = load_object(clspath)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 62, in load_object
    mod = import_module(module)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapy-redis'
```

The terminal shows an error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapy-redis'
But I have installed the module already[Screenshot of cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQPCQ.png)

Here is my Spider

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from distributePro.items import DistributeproItem
#Try to import the path,but fail
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\Program Files (x86)\python\Lib\site-packages\scrapy_redis')
from scrapy_redis.spiders import RedisCrawlSpider



class DisSpider(RedisCrawlSpider):
    name = 'distribute'
    #allowed_domains = ['www.xxx.comxxx.com']
    # start_urls = ['http://www.xxx.comxxx.com/']
    redis_key = 'sun'
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'id=1&page=\d+'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
       li_list = response.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/ul[2]/li')
       for li in li_list:
           news_num = li.xpath('./span[1]/text()').extract_first()
           news_title = li.xpath('span[3]/a/text()').extract_first()

           item = DistributeproItem()
           item['news_num'] = news_num
           item['news_title'] = news_title

           yield item
```

And my setting as below

```
# Scrapy settings for distributePro project
#
# For simplicity, this file contains only settings considered important or
# commonly used. You can find more settings consulting the documentation:
#
#     https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html
#     https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
#     https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html

BOT_NAME = 'distributePro'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['distributePro.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'distributePro.spiders'
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36'


# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
#USER_AGENT = 'distributePro (+http://www.yourdomain.com)'

# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False

# Configure maximum concurrent requests performed by Scrapy (default: 16)
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 32

# Configure a delay for requests for the same website (default: 0)
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay
# See also autothrottle settings and docs
#DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 3
# The download delay setting will honor only one of:
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 16
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP = 16

# Disable cookies (enabled by default)
#COOKIES_ENABLED = False

# Disable Telnet Console (enabled by default)
#TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED = False

# Override the default request headers:
#DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
#   'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
#   'Accept-Language': 'en',
#}

# Enable or disable spider middlewares
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html
#SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    'distributePro.middlewares.DistributeproSpiderMiddleware': 543,
#}

# Enable or disable downloader middlewares
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
#DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    'distributePro.middlewares.DistributeproDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
#}

# Enable or disable extensions
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html
#EXTENSIONS = {
#    'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole': None,
#}

# Configure item pipelines
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
# ITEM_PIPELINES = {
#    'distributePro.pipelines.DistributeproPipeline': 300,
# }

# Enable and configure the AutoThrottle extension (disabled by default)
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html
#AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
# The initial download delay
#AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 5
# The maximum download delay to be set in case of high latencies
#AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 60
# The average number of requests Scrapy should be sending in parallel to
# each remote server
#AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY = 1.0
# Enable showing throttling stats for every response received:
#AUTOTHROTTLE_DEBUG = False

# Enable and configure HTTP caching (disabled by default)
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#httpcache-middleware-settings
#HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True
#HTTPCACHE_EXPIRATION_SECS = 0
#HTTPCACHE_DIR = 'httpcache'
#HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_HTTP_CODES = []
#HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy.extensions.httpcache.FilesystemCacheStorage'

ITEM_PIPELINES={
    'scrapy-redis.pipelines.RedisPipeline':400
}

DUPEFILTER_CLASS = "scrapy_redis.dupefilter.RFPDuperFilter" 
SCHEDULER = "scrapy_redis.scheduler.Scheduler" 
SCHEDULER_PERSIST = "True" 
SCHEDULER_QUEUE_CLASS = 'scrapy_redis.queue.PriorityQueue'

REDIS_HOST = '127.0.0.1'
REDIS_PORT = 6379
```

How should I do?
Thanks

Comment: Please show errors and terminal output in your question in text form (formatted as code for readability) instead of as images.

Comment: Thaks for your advice Kemp

Comment: OK, I get it
you should check setting very carefully
I mistype the"scrapy_redis" as "scrapy-redis"
And "RFPDupeFilter" as "RFPDuperFilter"